When trying to use google-cloud storage, I get a FirebaseError
In my code I have
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";
const storage = new Storage();
console.log(storage); // Just so I don't get an unused variable error

As soon as I add this to my code, it breaks and gives me this Firebase Error. Before adding this, my code compiles properly. Why is the google cloud storage breaking my code and giving an error?

⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification

I have installed the google cloud storage package as seen in my
package.json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^7.14.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^13.0.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^6.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}


firebase-admin implicitly adds @google-cloud/storage and provides an API wrapper for it.  If you want to use firebase-admin, you shouldn't add it yourself - instead, you can just use the firebase-admin API directly to work with storage (which is exactly like that provided by @google-cloud/storage).  See the documentation about that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start

I've tried as instructed but am still encountering the same issue.
